# c quicksort memory leak by valgrind

Tags: c, list, memory-leaks, quicksort, heap-memory

I am facing a problem in initialising memory for this c quicksort code.
the sort algorithm is working flawlessly.
the only problem I have is by freeing the memory.

here is my code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "quicksort.h"

/*****************************************************
 * Die benoetigten structs findet Ihr in quicksort.h *
 *****************************************************/

void init_list(list* mylist)
{
// HIER Liste initialisieren
    mylist->first=NULL;
    mylist->last=NULL;
}


// Diese Funktion fügt Listenelemente an die Liste an
void insert_list(list_element* le, list* mylist)
{
    // HIER Code einfügen
    if (mylist->first == NULL) {
        le->next = NULL;
        mylist->first = le;
        mylist->last = le;
    }
    else {
        le->next = mylist->first;
        mylist->first = le;
    }
}
// Speicher für Listenelemente wieder freigeben
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    // HIER Code einfügen
    list_element *current = mylist->first;
    list_element *alt;
    while (current != NULL) {
        alt = current;
        current = current->next;
    free (alt);
    }
    free (current);
}


// Namen, Zahlen Paare in Liste einlesen
void read_data(char* filename, list* mylist)
{
        // HIER Code einfügen:
        // * Speicher allozieren
        // * Daten in list_element einlesen
        // * insert_front benutzen um list_element in Liste einzufügen
    FILE *fprint = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fprint == NULL){
        perror("input file könnte nicht geöffnet werden!");
    }
    while (1){
        char buffer[100];
        int counter ;
        int return_fscanf = fscanf (fprint ,"%s %d",buffer,&counter);
        if (return_fscanf == EOF){
            break;
        }
        if (return_fscanf != 2){
            printf ("Datei hat ungültiges Format.\n");
            break;
        }
        list_element *new_elem = malloc (sizeof (list_element));
        new_elem->password = malloc (sizeof (char)*strlen(buffer)+1);
        new_elem->count= counter;
        strncpy(new_elem->password, buffer,strlen(buffer));
        new_elem->next = NULL;
        insert_list (new_elem , mylist );
    }
}

// Liste teilen. Teillisten werden in left und right zurück gegeben
list_element* partition( list* input, list* left, list* right )
{
    // HIER Code einfügen:
    // parition() Funktion implementieren
    list_element* pivot=input->first;
    init_list(left);
    init_list(right);
    list_element* t=input->first->next;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        list_element* tnext=t->next;
        if((t->count) < (pivot->count))
        {
            insert_list(t,left);
        }
        else 
        {
            insert_list(t,right);
        }
        t=tnext;
    }
    return pivot;   
}

// Hauptfunktion des quicksort Algorithmus
void qsort_list(list* mylist)
{
    // HIER Code einfügen
    if(mylist->first == mylist->last) {
    }else{
        list LFT;
        list RGT;
        list* left=&LFT;
        list* right=&RGT;
        list_element* pivot = partition(mylist, left, right);
       qsort_list(left);
       qsort_list(right);

      if(left->first == NULL){
         mylist->first = pivot;
        }else{
            mylist->first = left->first;
            left->last->next = pivot;
        }
      if(right->first == NULL){
         pivot->next = 0;
         mylist->last = pivot;
        }else{
            pivot->next = right->first;
            mylist->last = right->last;
        }
    }
}

// Liste ausgeben
void print_list(list* mylist)
{
    // HIER Code einfügen:
    // * Laufe über die list_element in mylist und gebe sie aus.
    list_element *elem = mylist->first;
    while (elem != NULL) {
        printf("Passwort : %-15s Haeufigkeit : %-15d\n", elem->password ,             
elem->count);
    elem = elem->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

quicksort.h which contains struct looks like :

`    typedef struct list_element list_element;

```
struct list_element {
    char *password;
    int count;
    list_element* next;
};

typedef struct list list;

struct list {
list_element* first;
list_element* last;
};
void init_list( list* mylist );
void insert_list( list_element* le, list* mylist );
void free_list( list* mylist );
void read_data( char* filename, list* mylist );
list_element* partition( list* input, list* left, list* right );
void qsort_list( list* mylist );
void print_list( list* mylist );`
```

and here is valgrind report with leak-check=full:

```
==244== HEAP SUMMARY:
==244==     in use at exit: 1,343 bytes in 101 blocks
==244==   total heap usage: 203 allocs, 102 frees, 4,767 bytes allocated
==244==
==244== 791 bytes in 100 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==244==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==244==    by 0x4009D3: read_data (in /mnt/c/Users/YOGA/Desktop/introprog-wise1718/Aufgaben/Blatt10/Vorgaben/quicksort)
==244==    by 0x400CBD: main (in /mnt/c/Users/YOGA/Desktop/introprog-wise1718/Aufgaben/Blatt10/Vorgaben/quicksort)
==244==
==244== LEAK SUMMARY:
==244==    definitely lost: 791 bytes in 100 blocks
==244==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==244==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==244==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==244==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==244== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==244== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==244==
==244== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==244== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==244== ERROR SUMMARY: 101 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

edit: I got the leaks fixed. I will keep the original code unedited so the reader could see the changes.

I edited the void free_list, but I still had one leak caused by the fopen command which needed an fclose command at the end of void read_data.

```
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    // HIER Code einfügen
    list_element *current = mylist->first;
    list_element *alt=NULL;
    while (current) {
        alt = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(alt->password);
        free (alt);
    }
}
```

Comment: valgrind gave you the answer: the memory leak is at `malloc`, in `read_data`. Can I know how you compiled? Because if you compile with higher level of debug you can exactly now the lines corresponding to the memory leaks. Anyway you need to `free` after your malloc.

Comment: exactly !! all my tries emptying the malloc returns with whether no leaks but funky looking results, or the right results but still 201 leaks.
any clearer suggestions on how to do free right ?

Comment: I use gcc -std=c99 -Wall to compile
and valgrind --leak-check=full for leak check

Comment: Hi LazerDance , Valgrind never lies.In my opinion  , it's one of the best tools for leakes.

Comment: I see that you free any node (correct) have you also free(*list) its self??

Comment: @machine_1 then its obvious "awesome" wasnt meant for you.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that you're allocating memory in two lines (through malloc) but you're not freeing *all* of that memory later on.

from what i can see you're missing a free for the corresponding malloc `new_elem->password = malloc (sizeof (char)*strlen(buffer)+1);`... but my c++ is rusty so i could've missed one.

Comment: exactly !!! I tried to empty new_elem->password but with each try I end up having completely wiped out password list in the result, or having the same number of leaks.
any more detailed suggestions ? Id appreciate an example of how to empty allocated memory for (password) part right.

Comment: if that's the case then aren't you just freeing the memory before you're done using it?

Comment: totally agree !!
any suggestions where exactly I should free the memory ?
sorry but my c background is only 3 months old.

Comment: remove "free (current);" in the function void free_list(list* mylist). You don't need to free a NULL pointer.

Comment: I already did. this doesnt change anything. I still have the same number of leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I see a call of **fopen** but no call of **fclose**? Maybe thats your leak?

Comment: oooh that's a good one, yes leaving handle open will create leaks in the kernel handles

Comment: good advice !! I tried it but it didnt have any influence on the program (same result and same amount of leaks)

Comment: That very much looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not allowed to comment on questions with a bad reputation...